# ImageView inside transparent Toobar is not visible

Tags: android, xml

I am working on an Android App , Here I am trying to put **ImageView** as a child of transparent Toolbar, but ImageView is not visible in XML preview as well on Android Device both , I visited over stackoverflow but no luck .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/upButton"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:onClick="uphandler"
        android:src="@drawable/call"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Help me please .

Comment: try to change your drawable because i tried your code and it works perfectly.

Comment: @BOUTERBIATOualid I tried ,but no luck.

Comment: what's the size of your drawable?

Comment: it's 36x36 for hdpi .

Comment: try with 24*24 drawable

Comment: Tried but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this:
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/upButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="uphandler"
    android:src="@drawable/call"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: then your drawable image was problem code working fine@AndroidDev

Comment: Image is also perfect , I checked it .